# How Serialize Objects To String Using SimpleFramework

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc, simple-framework

Am working with GWT application and integrated with Simple framework to parse objects into XML, I have POJO classes on client side and use the parser on server side. I need to write the serialized object to String variable instead of file cause files not allowed in GWT App engine  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/M7Zo3U7CKD8.

**Current code I have in the server side on GWT RPC ServiceImpl**

```
File result = new File("c:/myXMLFile.xml");
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
MyBeanToSerialize beanToSerialize = new MyBeanToSerialize("firstName","LastName");
serializer.write(beanToSerialize, result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for returning String from the XML parser **by using the writer object instead of File the code is as the following:-**

```
String parser(){
 StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
 Serializer serializer = new Persister();
 MyBeanToSerialize beanToSerialize = new MyBeanToSerialize("firstName","LastName");
 serializer.write(beanToSerialize, writer);
return writer.getBuffer().toString();
)
```